# How is filesystem information stored on the hard disk

Tags: linux, filesystems, hard-disk

When we format a partition in a hard disk with a file system using `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1`, what's the data that is written on to `/dev/sdb1`.?

Some data identifying the filesystem type has to be written on to the partition. What is this data and to which area of the partition this data will be written.? I think that this data about the filesystem is required by other computers to identify what is the filesystem on a partition.

Comment: what research have you done? ...... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning

Comment: this gives info about partitioning and partition types. I asked about the filesystem data that is in a partition. i.e if a parition is formatted as ext4, where will be the information that this partition is ext4 is stored.

Comment: there are many links on that page ..... it is your job to do the actual research and follow them

Comment: Literally: *"What research have you done so far?"* Have you tried using a [search](http://lmgtfy.com/?s=d&iie=1&q=How+is+filesystem+information+stored+on+the+hard+disk) [engine](http://lmgtfy.com/?iie=1&q=How+is+filesystem+information+stored+on+the+hard+disk)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File systems all store information about themselves, often with some form of signature so that they can be identified. In Ext4’s case, the signature is 0xEF53 at offset 0x438, which you can see with `od`:

```
$ od -A x -x -j 1080 -N 2 /dev/<your device>
000438 ef53
00043a
```

This signature is part of the superblock, which contains information such as the overall size of the file system, the features it supports (*e.g.* whether it has a journal, uses extents, etc.), whether it’s clean or not...

For Ext4 you’ll find a description of the on-disk layout [on the Ext4 wiki](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout). Other file systems have similar documentation. You can find other signatures by reading [the file systems magic file](https://git.in-ulm.de/cbiedl/file/src/master/magic/Magdir/filesystems) used by  `file`.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. This answer actually clicked to me. However I believe term `FileSystem` is quite overloaded. For example, it see its defined as data structure and at some forum as software. Can you plz help with better understanding on this or pointer to understand this clear ?

Comment: Also another follow up question. If FileSystem is stored in secondary storage itself as superblock/inodes, then how same secondary storage medium (say pen drive) works across different OS since `superblock/inode` is linux thingy.